# Quando é recomendado o uso de um barramento de serviço (Enterprise Service Bus - ESB)?

Tags: web-service, arquitetura-de-software, soa

Estou no início do desenvolvimento de um sistema que prevê a comunicação com alguns outros sistemas através de Web Services. Ora nosso sistema será o provedor de serviços, ora será consumidor de serviços externos, sempre por meio de Web Services.

O uso de um barramento de serviço (Enterprise Service Bus - ESB) é indicado nesse caso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estas são algumas situações para as quais um barramento de serviço é uma solução **recomendada**:

- quando três ou mais aplicações precisam ser integradas de maneira orquestrada
- quando os serviços que serão incorporados são de provedores externos sobre os quais não há controle
- quando é necessário monitorar o nível de serviço dos provedores externos
- quando ocorrem mudanças nos contratos dos serviços (o ESB é capaz de fornecer um tratamento padrão para as mensagens enquanto ajustes são feitos para se adequar ao novo contrato)
- quando a arquitetura prevê o recebimento, processamento e produção de mensagens, especialmente quando há necessidade de um contexto transacional para as mensagens
- quando há a necessidade de comunicação com componentes e adaptadores para acessar aplicações legadas, que precisam ser acessadas de uma maneira padrão

Por outro lado, estas são algumas situações para as quais o uso de barramento de serviço **não é recomendado**:

- quando as integrações são ponto-a-ponto, sem necessidade de orquestração
- quando se utiliza apenas um tipo de protocolo, por exemplo apenas SOAP
- quando o volume de dados a ser enviado pelo barramento for muito grande (neste caso considerar ferramentas ETL e replicação de dados entre os bancos de dados envolvidos)
- quando há processos de negócios de longa duração, melhor implementados com ferrramentas de BPEL ou BPMN

Para o caso específico mencionado, parece que o uso de um barramento de serviço é um overhead desnecessário para o projeto.

Fontes:

[Enterprise Service Bus](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/soa/ind-soa-esb-1967705.html)

[Don’t use an ESB unless you absolutely, positively need one, Mule CTO warns](http://www.zdnet.com/article/dont-use-an-esb-unless-you-absolutely-positively-need-one-mule-cto-warns/)

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente você não precisa utilizar um Service Bus, já que optou pela comunicação através de Web Services. Em todo o caso, para ter uma ideia de como funciona e fazer um teste mais específico, crie um Service Bus no Azure e configure. É bem simples.

Dentro do Azure você pode encontrar o Service Bus Queues (permite uma comunicação unidirecional); o Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions (permite uma comunicação unidirecional usando assinaturas); o Service Bus Relay (proporciona uma comunicação bidirecional); e o Event Hubs (fornece o ingresso de eventos e telemetria para a nuvem).

Para maiores informações acesse o link: http://talkitbr.com/2015/06/19/azure-service-bus/

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar um barramento, quando ver a necessidade de comunicação entre os sistemas onde uma integração de um depende de outra.

Por exemplo: Você chama um serviço de um middleware, e esse middleware chama outros serviços de outros middlewares para juntar tudo e retornar e dar sua resposta.

Você vê a necessidade de orquestração ai certo ?
é nessa hora que vc deve recorrer a um ESB, pela abstração de camadas e orquestração.